# Why the thread doesn't joins when closing application?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I made a WPF application with a progressbar. The value of the progressbar is getting updated to a random value in a "while"-loop in the function "Background_Work". This function runs in a seperate thread.
If I close the window, I want to end the function (by ending the "while"-loop) and join the thread.

The problem is, that in some cases the window freezes and doesn't close.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Random random;
        Thread background_work;
        bool running;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            random = new Random();
            background_work = new Thread(Background_Work);

            running = true;
            background_work.IsBackground = true;
            background_work.Start();
        }

        private void Background_Work()
        {
            while (running)
            {
                myBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { myBar.Value = random.Next(0, 100); });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            running = false;
            background_work.Join();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A thread with Dispatcher.Invoke and Thread.Sleep is absolutely the wrong approach. Use a DispatcherTimer instead.

Comment: ^^ here is a link to the docs: [DispatchTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks for the tipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is a combination of two things, which together cause a deadlock.

The first is that the `running` field is accessed from multiple threads, but isn't synchronized. If you access data from multiple threads, it *must* be locked. In this case, after the main thread sets the field to false, the background thread may read it as true for a while.

The second is that you call `Dispatcher.Invoke`, not `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. `Invoke` will post a message to the dispatcher's message queue, and will **wait** until that message has been processed, blocking the calling thread.

So what happens is:

1. The dispatcher thread sets `running` to `false`
2. The dispatcher thread blocks, waiting for the background thread to exit
3. The background thread finishes its sleep, incorrectly reads `running` as `true`, posts a message to the dispatcher thread's message queue, and blocks waiting for it to be processed
4. The message will never be processed, because the dispatcher thread is blocked waiting for the background thread to exit
5. The background thread will never exit, because it is blocked waiting for the message to be processed by the dispatcher thread
6. Deadlock

This is happening because you're breaking a number of different cardinal rules:

1. Never block the UI thread. Ever.
2. Never access shared state from two threads without a lock (or other synchronization). Ever.
3. Only use Invoke over BeginInvoke if you have a *really* good reason.

As the comments say, use a DispatcherTimer for this.

If you do find yourself needing to cancel a background thread, use a `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `background_work.Join()` blocks the currently thread while it waits for the `background_work` thread to naturally finish. You have that tread busy in a `while` loop so it never ends and thus your UI is waiting forever.

I'd suggest you avoid threads all together and use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading` for the WPF bits).

Then you can do this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Random random;
    IDisposable subscription;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        random = new Random();

        subscription =
            Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
                .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                .Subscribe(_ => myBar.Value = random.Next(0, 100));
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        subscription.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It makes things very easy.